# How to merge two sub-networks into a model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, deep-learning

I need to design a deep network with two sub networks.

```
1- The first network: (sub_net_1)
input_1 size: 128x128x1
output_1 size: 512x512x1

from elsewhere:
input_2 size: 512x512x4


concatenate(output_1, input_2)

2- The second network: (sub_net_2)
input_3 size: 512x512x5
```

I need to concatenate the output_1 with input_2 of the same size and feed it to the network

I know the simple way of defining a model in tensorflow is 
Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
How can I define the model for my problem where I have two inputs of different sizes and need to train both sub-networks together?

here is the architecture of the network: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GicUm.jpg

Comment: so the input to sub_net_2 should be of shape (512, 512, 2) ?

Comment: The input of sub_net_2  is (512, 512, 5) that is by concatenating output of  sub_net_1 with size of (512, 512, 1) and input_2 with size of  (512, 512, 4)

Comment: `tf.concat([sub_net_1, input_2], axis=2)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the concatenate() function and pass the result as an input to subnet_2:

```
concat = concatenate([output_1, input_2])
input_3()(concat)
```

See here for an example: https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/lstm-with-char-embeddings-for-ner/